# "Import Error" when I upload .ipa file to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, application-loader

I'm trying to upload my iOS App to App Store but I have some issues to upload my .ipa file to iTunes Connect.

I'm trying to upload my .ipa file wheter through Application Loader or XCode and the uploading seems to be ok.

For a while if I look at Activity I see the build written "Processing" but immediately after iTunes Connect doesn't show the build and, when I check the delivery status of my App in Application Loader -> Window -> Delivery Status, I read that there was an

> "Import Error"

with no description of the error that occurred.

Which could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem thanks to the response Email from the App Store Team:

> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
>
> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to
>   the user how the app uses this data.

I do not know why I need these keys but I hope it will be useful to those who will have the same problem.